# Does Zombie link trigger when out of models?

Tags: zombicide

In Zombicide, if you have a character with the "zombie link" ability, does that ability trigger only when a spawn card says "all X 1 extra turn" or does it also trigger when you activate zombies due to a spawn where you don't have enough figures?

Comment: Probably isn't suppose to, but I'd allow it. Zombicide is about making it fun, so might as well give him this rare boon.

Comment: In Zombicide, you select the level of challenge (based on the scenario, which cards you include/exclude, which expansions you add it, etc.) This is just another variable you can tweak to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules as written state: `The Survivor plays an extra turn each time an
extra activation card is drawn in the Zombie pile.` ([source](http://zombicide.com/dl/Z-Skill-List-S2.pdf)).

This explicitly states that the extra turn is only gained when an activation card is drawn (those that say "all X 1 extra turn").
Note: this ability would also trigger at blue threat level, even though the zombies do not get an activation.

As stated in the comments though, it is your Zombicide game, so you can adjust the rules as you please. If you do decide to allow gaining extra turns from extra activations from having run out of zombie miniatures, I would recommend limiting the number of extra turns a surviver can get to 1 per round.